# numbering in beamer

Tags: beamer, numbering

new here and of course I have a question.
I am making a beamer presentation from a course and would like the numbering in beamer to be the same as in the course. The course is split into chapters (sections) and each chapter has several subsections. I want consecutive numbers throughout a chapter (so no mention of the subsection and I want that consecutive numbering to start again at 1 with each following chapter. So the numbers for all items (theorems, lemmas, remarks, etc should be of type 4.6 where 4 is the chapter number and 6 the consecutive number of the item. I've tried various things but it remains a mess. Simply copying the preamble from the course does not work. Can someone please help me. Thanks a lot, Bob.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I would like to know what commands I have to give in the preamble of a beamer file so that the numbering of theorems , lemmas, remarks, etc would be of type m.n where m is the section number and n is the number of the n-th item in th section. The n should start at 1 with each new section. section 1 numbers 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, etc, section 2 numbers 2.1, 2.2, 2.3 etc.

Comment: I think that `counterwithin{theorem}{section}` and similar should work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply Bernard. Sorry to react only now, I was away. Unfortunately it does not seem to work. It does what it should do but not in sections rather in subsections. So I get m.n where m is the subsection and n the nth item in that subsection. And then when we go to the next section it continues numbering subsections so the second section now has numbers in the first subsection like 4.1, 4.2 etc. Maybe a small adaptation of the command you gave will solve it?